# Copy value of active cell, open browser, search active cell value in search box, then fetch the URL of the searched webpage

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to:
Get the value of an active cell (a property address)
Open Edge with a Selenium Edge Driver to [www.redfin.com](http://www.redfin.com)
Search the value of the cell (the property address)
Fetch the URL from the search results webpage
Write the URL hyperlink back to the active cell, with value in the cell still intact, but now it's a hyperlink that you can click to return the search results page.

```vb
' Create a new instance of the Edge WebDriver
Dim driver As New WebDriver

Sub FetchURL()
' Get the value from the active cell

Dim cellValue As String
cellValue = ActiveCell.Value
 
' Start the Edge browser
driver.Start "Edge", "msedgedriver.exe"

' Navigate to the Redfin search page
driver.Get "https://www.redfin.com"

' Find the search bar and enter the search term
Dim searchBox As WebElement
Set searchBox = driver.FindElementByCss("input[class='search-input-box']")
searchBox.SendKeys cellValue
searchBox.Submit

' Wait for the search results to appear
'driver.Wait 5000, "div[class='homes summary']"

' Get the URL of the search results page
Dim pageURL As String
pageURL = driver.Url

' Write the URL back to Excel with a hyperlink
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:=pageURL, TextToDisplay:=ActiveCell.Value

' Do not close the browser or release the driver object

End Sub
```

It's just copying [www.redfin.com](http://www.redfin.com) to the hyperlink, and not the URL of the searched property page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a wait period to enable the searched for address page to load.  Otherwise you will get the original URL.  Add a `driver.wait 1000` to your code after you Submit the search box.